# Magento 2 custom ajax request

Tags: magento2, ajax

In my custom module have a custom ajax request for sending selected date (datepicker) to controller and found this exception when access controller

> Block1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $resultJsonFactory of Larsa\ASlider\Controller\Index\indexquote

Controller:

```
namespace Larsa\ASlider\Controller\Index; 
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
protected $resultJsonFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax())
    {
        return $result->setData([
            'test'=>'test'
        ]);
    }
}}
```

JS:

```
var AjaxUrl = 'workshop/index/index'; 
    $('#datePicker').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {
            $.ajax({
                showLoader: true, 
                url: AjaxUrl,
                data: {
                    date: $("#datePicker").datepicker("getDate")
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert('success');
            }).error(function () {
                alert('error');
            });
        }
    });
    $('#datePicker').show();
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Please share the full code Action file?

Comment: Am just edited the post

Comment: Is this frontend URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this frontend URL

Then you cannot inject admin context class `\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,` here. That way you are getting the error.

Change this class to  `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context`

after that do the Di compile properly.

Comment: wait, how do you know that it's a backend request? Does not seem like it. I would argue that the Interceptor class likely must be deleted / regenerated

Comment: aah,you are right. We are  not sure this is frontend or admin URL.

Comment: its frontend url

Comment: what do you mean by "Di compile" ?

Comment: setup:di: compile

Comment: I guess its obvious that its a frontend controller , check the namespace .

Comment: Thanks alot it worked, the issue was the context class namespace,it worked even i didn't do Di complie

Answer (score 0):

Use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context

Instead of :

\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context